# Differentiation Proof

Tags: real-analysis

Good evening everybody (or morning, wherever you're at).
I am in need of assistance:
Let $g: [0,2] \rightarrow R$  be a differentiable function such that $g(0)=g(2)$. Prove there exists two constants $a$ and $b$ in $(0,2)$ such that $g'(b)=-g'(a)$ and $a\neq b$.
I am not confident in the direction I am going with this one. I know that by the mean value theorem there's a constant $c$ where $g(c)=0$, since $g(2)-g(0)=0$. This $c$ should be a local maximum or minimum of $g$. Assuming it's a local max, there's some $\delta$ such that for any $x$ in the interval $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$, $g(x)\leq g(c)$. My idea is to set $a$ equal to $c-\delta$ and $b$ equal to $c+\delta$. Then, by the mean value theorem, the limit as $a\rightarrow c$ of $(g(a)-g(c))/(a-c)$ exists. So does the limit as $b\rightarrow c$ of $(g(b)-g(c))/(b-c)$. The first limit equals the limit as $c-\delta \rightarrow c$ of $(g(c-\delta)-g(c))/(-\delta)$, and the second limit equals the limit as $c+\delta \rightarrow c$ of $(g(c-\delta)-g(c))/(\delta)$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* One might use the MVT twice. Once for $g(1)-g(0)$ and once for $g(2)-g(1)$. Notice that $g(2)-g(1)=-(g(1)-g(0))$.

Comment: This was a simple and effective trick. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If $g$ is constant the answer is obvious.  So assume $g$ is not constant.  Let $A = g'([0,2]) \equiv \{g'(x) \mid  0 \leq x \leq 2\}$.   If $A \subset [0, \infty)$, then $g$ would be nondecreasing, and since $g$ is not constant, $g(0) < g(2)$.  So $A  \not\subset [0,\infty)$.  Similarly $A \not\subset (-\infty,0]$. So $A$ contains a negative number and a positive number.  By the Intermediate Value Theorem, $A$ is connected, so there exists $d>0$ small enough so $d, -d \in A$.

Comment: Thank you for your proof, it's very intuitive as well. Makes me realize just how many ways there are to prove the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $f(x)= g(x)-g(2-x)$ and apply Rolle's theorem to $f(x)$ on $[0, 2]$.

Comment: Ah, Rolle's theorem would make sense here, seeing as how $f(0)$ and $f(2)$ are both $0$. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.

Comment: How do you manage the case $c = 1 $ in the conclusion $f'(c) = 0$?